# Multiple moving objects of the same type

Tags: java, object

I've started to do a little game in java.Something like a maze. But I have a little problem with the "enemies".

I have a class "Ball" that creates the player and a class "Enemy" which I would like to use to create more than one of that type.The enemies are squares and i need a lot of them on specific coords so i will have to move the ball up and down while the squares move sideways to left.I don't know how specific those indications are.But I only managed to create one moving square ore more but those don't move.

Any of you that might know and needs more info please ask for it and I will send u the code or what u need.
Thanks!

ENEMY Class:

```
public class Enemy {

int Y = 20;
private static final int WIDTH = 60;
private static final int HEIGHT = 50;
int x = 1000;
private Game game;

public Enemy(Game game) {
    this.game = game;

}
public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillRect(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

}
public void move() {
        x = x - 1;
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

public int getTopY() {
    return Y;}
```

BALL Class:

```
public class Ball {
    private static final int DIAMETRU = 30;
    int x = 200;
    int y = 0;
    private Game game;

    public Ball(Game game) {
        this.game= game;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            y = y - 5;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            y = y + 5;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    void move(){

        if (collision()){
            x = x - 5;
        }
        if (x == 25)
            game.gameOver();
    }
    private boolean collision() {
        return game.enemy.getBounds().intersects(getBounds());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        g.fillOval(x, y, DIAMETRU, DIAMETRU);
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, DIAMETRU, DIAMETRU);
    }
}
```

Game Class

```
public class Game extends JPanel {

    Ball ball = new Ball(this);
    GameOver go = new GameOver(this);
    Enemy enemy = new Enemy(this);


    public Game() {
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                ball.keyReleased(e);
            }
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                ball.keyPressed(e);
            }
        });
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    private void move() {
        enemy.move();
        ball.move();


    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ball.paint(g2d);
        enemy.paint(g2d);
        go.paint(g2d);
    }

    public void gameOver() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over", "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        System.exit(ABORT);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Maze");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(1000,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {
            game.move();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the **relevant** code snippets here on SO. Second, you should ask a specific question.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form. 3) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: *"This is more than u need.THX"*  It seems you're not in a position to know what we need in order to solve this.  If you knew what was needed, you'd be 99% of the way to solving it on your own.  Also, stop using nonsense spelling like 'u' and 'thx'.  These are not text message we need to peck out on a phone.  You have a full keyboard, use it to good effect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for anyone who reads this question it is unclear how you render all your stuff which is required for a basic understanding of the question.

Here is a **3D** solution:
You could use the j3d-package, a good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.java3d.org/tutorial.html). Read it through to the end, maybe it helps you out alone.

To move the objects keep a list of them somewhere (maybe an 'ArrayList') and update them frequently to let them move.

If you read the tutorial, especially the part [positioning](http://www.java3d.org/position.html) then you should know how to position your objects in the world. If you understood the concept of TransformGroups then you could realize that in order to manipulate the object's position you have to keep its TransformGroup around somewhere. That means that your enemy-class could look like this:

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
import javax.vecmath.*;
class Enemy {
    private TransformGroup tg; //Reference to move the object and also 
                               // has to be added to the world, see tutorial
    private ColorCube cube; //Reference to the cube, I don't exactly know why, could come in handy
    public Enemy() {
        Transform t = new Transform3D();
        this.tg = new TransformGroup();
        this.cube = new ColorCube(0.3); //Light red
        t.setTranslation(Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); //Init with starting position
        this.tg.setTransform(t);
    }

    public void reposition() {
        //Call this for reposition and do your things
        // manipulate the TransformGroup for example
    }
    public TransformGroup getTg() { //So you can add it to the world after instanciating a new object
        return this.tg;
    }
}
```

The class of your character would look kinda the same maybe you could add some polymorphism to it if you know what that is to simplify how to deal with enemies and your own class at the same time (they both need to be updated frequently).